# Shell script Reverse Geocode?

Tags: reverse-geocoding

Is it possible how to reverse Zipcode using shellscript? i am try to get zipcode from latitude and longitude so should is it possible?

location=$(curl -s http://freegeoip.net/csv/$1)
  echo $location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTFM,  http:freegeoip.net/ says

freegeoip.net/{format}/{IP_or_hostname}

This does not support giving it a lat,lon location.

google: reverse geocode postal code

Has lots of solutions.

Comment: i want to try to get postal code using  cordinates so how to gwt using shellscript?